# How to select rows where for same `userid` other field has specific values?

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of table (simplified):

```
orders           sample data below
---------------------------------------------
id INT:          1     2     3     4     5
userid INT       10    10    10    20    20
status CHAR(1)   A     A     B     A     C
```

and want to select all orders where for each `userid` status is `IN ('A','B')` but have no orders at all `IN ('C','D')`.

**So output for above data would give orders with ID=1, 2 and 3**. User ID=10 have orders A and B, but no C or D.

In other words: Select orders for customers who have orders with status A or B, but none of statuses C or D.

I started with this:

```
SELECT 
    xcart_orders.orderid, 
    xcart_orders.*          
    FROM xcart_orders 
    JOIN (
        select count(*) as bad_statuses, userid from xcart_orders 
        where status in ('C','D') 
        group by userid 
    ) bo 
    ON bo.userid=xcart_orders.userid 
    JOIN (
        select count(*) as good_statuses, userid from xcart_orders 
        where status in ('A','B') 
        group by userid 
    ) bo2 
    ON bo2.userid=xcart_orders.userid 
    WHERE bo2.good_statuses>0 and bo.bad_statuses=0
```

but think `count(*)` won't return zero for 'bad' statuses, so I get no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an aggregation without `GROUP BY` and for check the result you need us `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

```
SELECT 
    xcart_orders.orderid, 
    xcart_orders.*, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN xcart_orders.status in ('C','D') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bad_statuses, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN xcart_orders.status in ('A','B') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS good_statuses 
FROM xcart_orders 
GROUP BY orderid
HAVING bad_statuses = 0 
   AND good_statuses > 0
```

Please be aware the fields you get from `xcart_orders.*` will be random (or non deterministc) if you need a particular one you need to order it first.

- First you GROUP BY `user_id` to check if have any status different to `'A', 'B'`
- Then you select orders from those `user_id`:

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/VYXZ71168)

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM orders1
GROUP BY `user_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN `status` IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 END);


SELECT *
FROM orders1
WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `user_id`
                    FROM orders1
                    GROUP BY `user_id`
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN `status` IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 END)
                   );
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I always get sum of bad and good statuses zero or one, something is wrong. Orders to sum must have same `userid`. Do I have to join same table again to calculate sums?

Comment: can you provide some data and expected output? I could give you a more specific answer.

Comment: I have added my new query, can you help please?

Comment: Check the new query.

Comment: I ended calculating all statuses together and only good statuses (with 2 joins), than compare if number is same. Thanks.